# How can you statically compile Microsoft .NET code?

Tags: .net, mono

I saw this [Ars Article](http://arstechnica.com/news.ars/post/20090108-open-source-mono-framework-brings-c-to-iphone-and-wii.html)  about .NET Mono version  being used to statically compiled and not have the JIT or CLR for the iPhone & Wii.  I'm assuming you can also do this for PC's w/o .NET installed.  The articles seem to imply this can only be done w/ Mono, but does anyone here know if there's a way to do it with Microsoft .Net implementation?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few tools that allow you to do this. There are some drawbacks because there are actually good reasons to have an updatable framework. However, there are definitely some advantages. One of the better products is PostBuild:

http://www.xenocode.com/Landing/Run-NET-Without-NET.aspx?gclid=CNWvof_ZgpgCFRRhnAodsgLkDQ

Comment: @Bobby - have you used this?  I've heard some things about it in passing, but I've never come across anyone that's used it and it's pretty pricy to consider purely for experimentation...

Comment: Yeah, I used this on some small applications. This were small apps where the users had some paranoia about the .NET framework after I had already devloped the app. Also, I tried some toy apps. Haven't tried a big application with it; it wouldn't surprise me if there were some strange bugs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate issues here. The compilation part can be done on .net with [ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(VS.71).aspx).

The other issue is the [missing linker](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/PleaseLinker.html) in .net. Its job ( if it existed ) is to just take the needed part from the framework. And removing the need for full .net installation on the client. As other suggested, there are alternative for linker in .net. Not that I tried any of them.

Comment: Microsoft could have bypassed all this nonsense by bundling it into the operating system and service packs. I think by not doing this they caused a lot of confusion and misplaced paranoia among the general audience of IT non-programmers. It just presented an unnecessary stumbling block.

Answer (score 0):

Salamander .NET Linker is one of the tools that can do this on the PC:

http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, "[ngen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(VS.80).aspx)" can pre-JIT an app. There are [other tools](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#framework.required) for avoiding having a full .NET install, but I try to avoid them. In general: yes, you need a framework (but it could be Client Profile, Compact Framework, Micro Framework, or Silverlight if you want light-weight; all are MS CLR variants).